# How can I ensure my font renders properly on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

I'm using a personal font on a web app that renders perfectly well in all major browsers, except for IE (surprise, surprise).

How can I ensure users on IE will view the same font type that I've uploaded onto my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

Comment: have you tried using FontSquirrel to generate your css based on the fonts you supply?